# Creating Many New Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

In a program I'm writing, I currently have a class that looks like...

```
public class Plane {
    int[][] planes = new int[5][5];
}
```

An array is created in this class that has 5 rows and 5 columns. Each row of the array is supposed to contain the details of different 'planes', which are just lines. Each column will contain a different value that is related to the line that I'll have to access later, such as the X and Y values of its start point and its end point, its slope, its y-intercept, etc. In the beginning of the program, though, the user will have the option to create as many lines as they want, and they are requested for the details of that plane, which is currently stored in the "planes" array.

This program would probably be a lot neater if, instead of having a huge array, and creating a new row in that array for every line they wanted to create, I want to create a new "plane" object, and each object will contain the start and end point, slope, and y-intercept details of itself.

The code I have in my main class currently prompts the user, asking them if they want to create a new line. If they say yes, they are then prompted to enter the necessary information about it. After entering the information, they're again prompted, asking if they'd like to create *another* line, and it repeats. How could I restructure my program to create a new class for each line the user would want to make? How would I reference the variables of those classes when I have to assign values to them? How would I keep track of the classes created?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may want to have a look at ArrayList and Vector, and maybe even HashMap for letting you do things like `allThePlanes.get(planeIdentifier)` rather than relying on list positions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Alright. I've looked at it and I think it'd work well here. Do you have any idea of how I'd go about creating the names of the different classes? The classes would, of course, have to change for each different class that was made, as to keep it's name unique. I'm not sure how'd I'd integrate an incrementing integer into the names of classes. Or would the naming of the classes be irrelevant here? Do vectors store objects and refer to them based on their index, rather than the name of the object?

Comment: Just follow the best practice of "calling things what they are". If you have a row of planes, `PlaneRow` is apt. If that row represents a lot, `Lot` works perfectly fine. If a set of rows constitutes an airfield, `AirField`, etc. But the real question you need to ask is whether your datastructure should capture the plane position, or whether that should just be a property of Planes themselves, with an `AirField.add(Plane p)` that makes sure the plane gets a valid position assigned.